# Data from two modems for faster browsing?

Tags: networking, internet, modem, bandwidth

I'm stuck with DSL Lite (a slow Internet connection).

Is it possible to speed up my AT&T 'DSL Lite' connection by augmenting it with some bandwidth from my Cellphone's tethered 'hot-spot' connection?

I often use my cellphone's tethered hotspot because it is much faster than my DSL-Lite connection; however, I find it is too expensive to use regularly. It seems like I should be able to combine these two data streams and use them simultaneously.

My current thinking is that some software might exist that makes it possible to use the cheapest bandwidth first (ATT's DSL-Lite) and leave it on (always flowing) but when the connection pauses/waits/bottlenecks/etc., it would then get a boost of bandwidth from the cellphone hotspot.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows you might get one of the methonds from this wiki-like page to work:

[Combine-Two-Internet-Connections.](http://www.wikihow.com/Combine-Two-Internet-Connections)

Or use the following link for a similar superuser question:

[superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/346185/3g-adsl-combined-speed)

For:

> some software might exist that makes it possible to use the cheapest bandwidth first

this might get difficult to realize, as far as I know the market is not broad enough for such a specific request. I might be wrong.